# How to view a JSON file in Django

Tags: json, django, sqlite

So I have a JSON file and I want to iterate over it and display the information using Django. How do I do that and do I need to set up a Model like normal? How do I transfer this data to the database model using SQLite?

I found this code on a similar stackoverflow question but I don't know how to show the data like via HTTPResponse so the user can view the data:

```
import json

json_data = open('/static/prices.json')   
data1 = json.load(json_data) // deserialises it
data2 = json.dumps(json_data) // json formatted string

json_data.close()
```

Comment: Do you want to parse the json data or only display it? And do you want to display this formatted or just as plain json?

Comment: I don't understand what parsing is. What does it mean? The phone numbers need to be formatted with a 0 at the front. Everything else looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1: Use loaddata

Django provided `loaddata` command to 'trasfer' data from json|xml|.. to Model.
To use `loaddata`, Move your file `prices.json` to `yourapp/fixtures` and reformat:

```
[{
    "model": "yourapp.yourmodel",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
        "name": "Item A",
        "price": 1
    }
}, {
    "model": "yourapp.yourmodel",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
        "name": "Item B",
        "price": 2
    }
}]
```

Then run command `python manage.py loaddata prices`

### Option 2: Use migration

In case you don't want to change your file format, create an empty migration

`python manage.py makemigrations yourapp --empty`

In new migration file, add `insert_price`, something like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import json
from django.db import models, migrations
from yourapp.models import Model


def insert_price(apps, schema_editor):
    with open('/path/to/prices.json') as data_file:    
        data = json.load(data_file)

    for item in data:
        # Update, map field for item to make it match with Model
        # item['description'] = 'Just kidding'
        Model.objects.create(**item)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourapp', '000_previous_depends'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(insert_price),
    ]
```

Finally, apply that migration `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: There is some cases that you just want to display a third party json/api and you just want to display it without doing a bunch of requests in the endpoint using APIView from rest_framework. Therefore, in this case fixtures and migrations are useless.